# While Loop Only Running Once?

Tags: javascript

Kind of stumped as to why my numerical method to calculate derivatives is not looping despite `Math.abs(v1-v2)` definitely being greater than `1E-7`:

```
derivative:function(f,o,x){
    var h=0.01;
    switch(o){
        case 1:
            //v1=(f(x+h)-f(x))/h;
            var v1=(-f(x+2*h)+8*f(x+h)-8*f(x-h)+f(x-2*h))/(12*h);
            while(typeof v2==='undefined' || Math.abs(v1-v2)>1E-7) {
                h-=h/2;
                //v2=(f(x+h)-f(x))/h;
                v2=(-f(x+2*h)+8*f(x+h)-8*f(x-h)+f(x-2*h))/(12*h);
                v1=v2;
            }
            return v2;

        ...

        default:
            return 0;
    }
}
```

It's probably just me having a brain fart though. Any ideas *on how to fix it*?

Comment: What values do you pass in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to move the definition of `v1` inside the loop:

```
var h=1,v1,v2;

...

while((typeof v1==='undefined' && typeof v2==='undefined') || Math.abs(v1-v2)>1E-7) {
    //v2=(f(x+h)-f(x))/h;
    v1=(-f(x+2*h)+8*f(x+h)-8*f(x-h)+f(x-2*h))/(12*h);
    h-=h/2;
    v2=(-f(x+2*h)+8*f(x+h)-8*f(x-h)+f(x-2*h))/(12*h);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The first time the loop runs, it sets v2, so `typeof v2==='undefined'` is no longer true. It also sets `v1=v2`, so `Math.abs(v1-v2)===0`, so the second condition is false, as well. Thus, neither condition is true, so the loop exits.

Answer (score 0):

The last thing in your while loop in v1=v2 so on the next iteration of the while loop,  Math.abs(v1-v2) === 0

Answer (score 0):

Well, v1-v2 == 0, since v1=v2.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your last statement inside the while-loop. I guess you wanted to do this:

```
derivative:function(f,o,x){
    var h=0.01;
    switch(o){
        case 1:
            var v1=(-f(x+2*h)+8*f(x+h)-8*f(x-h)+f(x-2*h))/(12*h);
            while(typeof v2==='undefined' || Math.abs(v1-v2)>1E-7) {
                v2=v1;
                h-=h/2;
                v1=(-f(x+2*h)+8*f(x+h)-8*f(x-h)+f(x-2*h))/(12*h);
            }
            return v1;

        ...

        default:
            return 0;
    }
}
```